# Is there a way to do this in FullCalendar jquery

Tags: fullcalendar

You can make description that says Kids Art School Day in April 12 to April 17th. It will make a bar across from that date like this"Kids Art School Day". How do you make each day  show the same thing like a tradition paper calendar. April 12 says "Kids Art School Day", April 13 says "Kids Art School Day", April 14 says "Kids Art School Day", ........ all saying the same thing? I can do it in the events ,like this

```
                'title': 'Kids Art School Day ',
                'start': '2015-04-13',
                'end': '2015-07-13',
                'color': '#FFFFFF',
                'textColor': '#3300FF'


                'title': 'Kids Art School Day ',
                'start': '2015-04-14',
                'end': '2015-07-14',
                'color': '#FFFFFF',
                'textColor': '#3300FF'
```

I did a range but they want it to show each box the same thing..beats me.. ideas? In the calendar there is a lot of them.. making this json readable will be too much...

Comment: You want each box (1 day in month view) to show the title of the event?

Comment: Yes like a regular paper calendar it shows same event per box...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly supported and so the solution is a little tricky.

Essentially, you break up the events into single day events when they are loaded. Use the [function event source](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) for this.

```js
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    //Get the events with an ajax call or whatever.
    //Here, they're just declared globally as 'events'
    var chunkedEvents = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var days = moment(events[i].end).diff(events[i].start, 'days'); //length of event
        if (typeof events[i].end !== "undefined" && days > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j <= days; j++) {
                chunkedEvents.push($.extend({}, events[i], {
                    start: moment(events[i].start).subtract(j, 'days'),
                    end: moment(events[i].end).subtract(days + j, 'days')
                }))
            }
        } else {
            chunkedEvents.push(events[i]);
        }
    }
    callback(chunkedEvents);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/slicedtoad/635t5ap4/3/)